# Magento2 - Copy quote fields to order fields

Tags: magento2, sales-order, quoteitem

In Magento2, i want to copy the quote custo  fields into order custom fields, i.e.

say, i have created a manufacturer column in quote_item which needs to be copied into sales_order_item table, manufacturer column, during order placed.

In Magento1, it was possible through

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To copy quote item fields to sale order item fields, we need to declare these fields in **fieldset.xml**

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/fieldset.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <!-- Copy quote to sale order fields -->
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote">
            <field name="custom_attribute">
                <aspect name="to_order" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- Copy quote item to sale order item fields-->
        <fieldset id="quote_convert_item">
            <field name="manufacturer">
                <aspect name="to_order_item" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

[EDIT]

Seem that we need to use Observer `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` to assign the new fields:

Comment: i am using same way but not working for me ! 
<fieldset id="sales_convert_quote">
            <field name="custom_attribute">
                <aspect name="to_order" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>

Comment: I want copy data 'quote_item' table filed 'test' to 'sales_order_item' field 'test' so how is it possible ?

Answer (score 6):

On 2.1.3 at least, doing it through **fieldset.xml** does not work.

I had to use the event *sales_model_service_quote_submit_before* , which is fired in function *submitQuote* of *Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement*

```
$order->setCustomerLastname($quote->getCustomerLastname());

$this->eventManager->dispatch(
                'sales_model_service_quote_submit_before',
                [
                    'order' => $order,
                    'quote' => $quote
                ]
            );
```